# Can a woman be one of the three for hatares nedarim?

Tags: women, nedarim-shevuot

Can a woman be one of the three witnesses/part of the beis din for hatares nedarim (annulment of vows)?

Comment: 3 dayanim must to be men

Comment: @kouty Who said this is a formal Din? Many permit it to be done at night, for instance.

Comment: @ Double AA thank you I did not know this

Answer (score 4):

Source:
http://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Hatarat_Nedarim

> Rabbi Akiva Eiger (comments on [Shulchan Aruch YD 228](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=yd_x6634):1) who writes that while relatives can serve as a Bet Din for Hatarat Nedarim, a woman can't serve on such a Bet Din.

Answer (score 0):

See Tur YD 228, 3

> ואפילו מעומד ובקרובים ובשבת
>
> Even if the judges stand up, are relatives and even at Shabbat.

Bet Yossef explain that this is the conclusion of the Gemara 77b in Nedarim.

> רבה אמר נשאלין נדרים עומד, יחידי, ובלילה ובשבת ובקרובים ואפילו היה להם פנאי מבעוד יום.‏

Women are not mentioned, but we may ask* for the difference between women and relatives. The answer is obvious. The relative is essentially a good Dayan, the situation is not good as Shabbat. But woman isn't unfit as the result of situation but essentially not valuable as Judge

(I see now that this is the svara of RAk A... :-)

---

- This is the lomdus of the question as explained @DoubleAA

We can ask a further questio. What is the din if 2 dayanim ate relative one to another.

I think that it is not good because of the self svara applied not only to daysn but to the whole judging entity.

Comment: @Double AA see the *